# Nesting if statement inside foreach loop using Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel blade and trying to nest an `if` statement inside a `foreach` loop.  I want to show a different link depending on whether a field in my table equals `Submitted`.  I have written the following code in my view:

```
         @foreach($plans as $plan)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$plan->id}}</td>
                {{-- If the Plan Submission has been submitted, the link should bring the user to the Show function which is view only.  Cannot have user editing Plan Submission after it has been submitted. --}}
                @if ({{$plan->status}}=='Submitted')
                    <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/show">Click Here</a></td>
                @else    
                    <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/edit">Click Here</a></td>
                @endif
```

I am getting this error:  syntax error

```
unexpected '<'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
     @foreach($plans as $plan)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$plan->id}}</td>
            {{-- If the Plan Submission has been submitted, the link should bring the user to the Show function which is view only.  Cannot have user editing Plan Submission after it has been submitted. --}}
            @if ($plan->status == 'Submitted')
                <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/show">Click Here</a></td>
            @else    
                <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/edit">Click Here</a></td>
            @endif
```

It was `@if ({{$plan->status}}=='Submitted')`

No need for the `{{ }}` inside the if statement :)

So the change in total was:
`@if ({{$plan->status}}=='Submitted')` to `@if ($plan->status == 'Submitted')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@foreach($plans as $plan)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$plan->id}}</td>

                <td>
                   <a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/@if($plan->id=='submitted') show 
                     @else edit @endif">
                      Click Here
                    </a>
                </td>
          </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a syntax error.

```
{{$plan->status}}=='Submitted'
```

Inside if, you don't need to use `{{}}` as you are already writing PHP script using inline `@if`. We used `{{ }}` when we want to print a PHP variable within the HTML. You can read about [Laravel blade](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade) for more details.

#### Solution

Just replace `{{$plan->status}}=='Submitted'` with `$plan->status == 'Submitted'`.

---

#### Another way to implement the same just by using inline `if` statement.

```
@foreach($plans as $plan)
    @php 
        $url = "/basicinfo/{$plan->id}/";
        $url .= strtolower($plan->status) =='submitted' ? 'show' : 'edit';
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td> {{$plan->id}}</td>
        <td><a href={{$url}}>Click Here</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach;
```

NOTE: I've used [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) php function for better comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```php
@foreach($plans as $plan)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $plan->id }}</td>
        @if ($plan->status === 'Submitted')
            <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{ $plan->id }}/show">Click Here</a></td>
        @else
            <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/edit">Click Here</a></td>
        @endif
    </tr>
@endforeach
```